# How to create a kotlin live template for newInstance Fragments using Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, live-templates

I'm searching for a way to create a new Kotlin live code template so that whenever I type newIns.... it and hit tab it will be able to print the following as a live template choice:

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(b: Bundle): DetailsFragment {
        val frag = DetailsFragment()
        frag.arguments = b
        return frag
    }
}
```

In Java, it was done the same way and there is already a "newInstance" abbreviation and a live template exists in Android Studio. I want the same thing for Kotlin. Let me show you a photo :

[image]

Notice that, Java Android already has `newInstance` template. I want this for Kotlin. Here is what I have so far:

[image]

and the template code I have so far looks like this:

```
companion object { 
    fun newInstance($args$:Bundle):$fragment$ {
        $nullChecks$
        android.os.Bundle args = Bundle();
        $addArgs$
        $fragment$ fragment = $fragment$();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

but when I exit the settings and in Kotlin type the first few words of the abbreviation and hit tab or ctrl + spacebar on mac nothing happens. I guess I have the syntax wrong, I'm not sure. Anyone of suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Go to Live Templates section in Android Studio.

**For Windows:**

**File** > **Settings** > **Editor** > **Live Templates**

**For Mac:**

**Android Studio** > **Preferences** > **Editor** > **Live Templates**

**Step 2:**

Select **Kotlin** template group. Then tap on `+` present at the top-right corner of the popup. Select **Live Template**.

**Step 3:**

Now you can add your live template. Check at the bottom of the popup.

Add **abbreviation:** newInstance

Add **description:** Creates an instance of the fragment with arguments

Add **template text:**

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(args: Bundle): $fragment$ {
        val fragment = $fragment$()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

Add **applicable context**. Tap on `Define`. Select Kotlin from the list.

Select **Reformat according to style**

**Step 4:**

Tap on **Edit Variables** below the description.

Now tap on **Expression** for the variable name `fragment`. Tap on down arrow. You can see a list of expressions. From there select `kotlinClassName()`.

Tap on **OK** of the Edit Templates Variable

Now tap on **Apply** and **OK** of the Live Templates.

To check type `newInstance` in a Fragment written in Kotlin.

Comment: now i see the issue. i was not setting  the context. awesome answer. in the end it looks like this:   companion object {
    fun newInstance(b: Bundle?): $fragment$ {
        val fragment = $fragment$()
        fragment.arguments = b?:Bundle()
        return fragment
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simplified version (and more idiomatic) would be:

```
fun newInstance($args$) : $fragment$ = 
    $fragment$().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            $addArgs$
        }
    }
```

or

```
fun newInstance(args: Bundle) : $fragment$ = 
    $fragment$().apply {
        arguments = args
    }
```