# Quarkus qute template fragments & type safe checking in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-qute

In java, you define Qute template fragments like this:

```java
@CheckedTemplate
public static class Templates {
    public static native TemplateInstance foo(int a, int b);
    public static native TemplateInstance foo$sectionA(int a); 
    public static native TemplateInstance foo$sectionB(int b); 

    public static native TemplateInstance bar();
}
```

In Kotlin, you can't use "$" in methods. How do I define template fragments in Kotlin?

```kotlin
@CheckedTemplate
private object Templates {
    @JvmStatic
    external fun foo$fragment1(): TemplateInstance
}

Reason: Expecting member declaration
        external fun foo$fragment1(): TemplateInstance
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a kotlin live template for newInstance Fragments using Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473637/how-to-create-a-kotlin-live-template-for-newinstance-fragments-using-android-stu)

Comment: no, it's totally unrelated @Marsroverr

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use `$` in Kotlin function names, if you enclose the name into backticks: `\`foo$fragment1\``.